# What do bionic-wallpapers.xml and ubuntu-wallpapers.xml do?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell, desktop-background, xml

I came across these two files:

- /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/bionic-wallpapers.xml
- /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/ubuntu-wallpapers.xml

Can you explain what do these files do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are used to set up the wallpaper picker. See the name and the corresponding image of the possible wallpapers:

[image]

Top 3 are

```
/usr/share/backgrounds/budgie/coffee_on_bench_by_mikesh_kaos.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/budgie/camera_and_spectacles_by_bino_storyteller.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/budgie/bike_wheel_by_michal_kulesza.jpg
```

Each flavor of Ubuntu will have a xml with the name of the distro in it (I use Budgie, you use Gnome). Those are the distro and release specific wallpapers.

The one without the "bionic" holds the default wallpapers for that distro of Ubuntu (so Budgie, Gnome, etc each have their own default wallpapers). Those are at the end of the view:

[image]

Last but one row, one on the right is

```
/usr/share/backgrounds/Xplo_by_Hugo_Cliff.png
```

From the file browswer:

[image]

Bottom 3 are

```
/usr/share/backgrounds/budgie/ubuntu_budgie_wallpaper1.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/budgie/ubuntu_budgie_wallpaper1.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/budgie/ubuntu_budgie_wallpaper3.jpg
```

Also from the filebrowser:

[image]

Comment: So bionic-wallpapers.xml is used to display wall papers in the Window shown in your picture. What about ubuntu-wallpapers.xml? It's content is different to bionic-wallpapers.xml.

Comment: good enough @SunBear ?

Comment: This answer does not describe what the XML files do.

Comment: yes it does. it is used to show the images for wallpapers

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the wallpaper picker app? I would like to run it from cmdline. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The XML files you mention contain lists of wallpaper images, and the settings which should be applied by the background chooser, for what fill type, and background shading and colors, to use for that wallpaper.

Unfortunately, it seems most of them do not really use these files properly, and simply leave it at `zoom` with solid background color of black underneath the image (in case of transparency or unfilled area of the screen).